# JQuery Clear <ul> Two Menus Away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have three menus: College, Department and Program. When a College is clicked, the list of Departments belonging to that College is shown. When a Department is clicked, the list of Programs belonging to that Department is shown.

My problem is that when I click a new College, the Departments re-populate in the second list but I can't get the Programs in the third column to clear out. I've tried a bunch of different things with .nextAll() and .siblings() and whatnot, but nothing has worked yet.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <h4>Colleges</h4>
    <ul class="colleges-menu">
        <?php CommonFunctions::getCollege('list'); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <h4>Departments</h4>
    <ul id="departments" class="colleges-menu">

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <h4>Programs</h4>
    <ul id="programs" class="colleges-menu">

    </ul>
</div>
```

And the JQuery:

```
function ajaxLists(){   
    var entity = '.' + $(this).attr('class');
    var nextEntity;
    var value;
    var data; 
    switch(entity){
        case '.college':
            nextEntity = '#departments';
            value = $(this).val();
            data = {list_college: value};
            break;  
        case '.departments':
            nextEntity = '#programs';
            value = $(this).val();
            data = {list_departments: value};
            break;
        default:
            break;  
    }
    //this should ONLY run if we are selecting a college or department
    if(entity == '.college' || entity == '.departments'){
        $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
        $.ajax({
            url: "sort_college.php",
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function(info){
              $(nextEntity).html('');
              $(nextEntity).append(info);
              console.log(info);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("there's an error with AJAX");
            }
        }).done(function(){
            $("body").css("cursor", "default");
        }); //end ajax
    }
}
```

Comment: All your `ul` have the same class, and you're using a `case` to check them passing a class that doesn't exist.

Comment: To select an element you can rely on its ID. You don't need any _magic_ here. Just the basic `$('#your-element-id')`.

Comment: MelanciaUK - the class I am passing belongs to the AJAX-generated <li>s. Also I know I can use the ID but I'm trying to code this so I can add <ul>s in the future without having to worry about hard-coding IDs.

Comment: I see, but if you're using a `case` in your code, you won't be able to make it dynamic anyway.

Comment: Check this out. Maybe it can help you to go from there: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/btg57t0j/1/

Comment: Some improvements: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/btg57t0j/3/

Comment: I think that's it: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/btg57t0j/4/

Comment: This definitely looks in the right direction and certainly takes care of the dynamic aspect! The third menu is not populating so far but I can hopefully get that running.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. I'm sure you can tweak it to fit your requirements. The whole idea shouldn't go so further from that.

Comment: Yes thanks for the help and sticking with me on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that your code should fit further elements added in the future, you need to make sure you don't rely on hardcoded IDs, classes, etc.

This should solve your problem, or at least give you a good ground to go from there:

```
$(function () {
    $('.col-xs-4 .colleges-menu').on('click', 'li', function () {
        // Go up in this element parents until you reach the div.
        // Then you go to its next sibling and grab the ul.
        var nextEntity = $(this).parents('.col-xs-4').next().find('ul');
        // Self explanatory.
        var value = $(this).val();
        // Variable to store the data.
        var data = {};

        // If there's a nextEntity element, it means you didn't reach the last
        // set of options.
        if (nextEntity) {
            // Creating a property for data that is based in a variable.
            data["list_" + nextEntity.attr("id")] = value;

            $("body").css("cursor", "progress");

            $.ajax({
                url: "sort_college.php",
                type: "post",
                data: data,
                success: function (info) {
                    nextEntity.html('');
                    nextEntity.append(info);
                    console.log(info);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("there's an error with AJAX");
                }
            }).done(function () {
                $("body").css("cursor", "default");
            });
        }
    });
});
```